# Gradle.Properties changes not loading with the Micronaut Project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, micronaut

I have the below gradle configuration in Micronaut application using Intellj IDE

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Have the below multi-module project

[image]

With the base project settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'src'
include 'common', 'fete-bird-apigateway', 'fete-bird-product', 'fete-bird-order', 'fete-bird-payment', 'communication'
```

In each Micronaut application there is a Gradle.Properties file as below

[image]

If I make any changes to these files, there is no gradle loading change operation, however, on build.gradle the loading change operation is working fine.

In gradle.properties file I have a micronaut version

```
`micronautVersion=2.2.1 I` need to update the version to the latest version.
```

With only the micronaut project the changes for the .properties file work, but not with the multi-module project.

Repository to check - https://github.com/anandjaisy/micronaut-multimodule